# Laravel Livewire form, if validation fails, pivots don't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a form made with Livewire in Laravel.

This is the Livewire controller

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Rules\Mobile;

class Form extends Component
{
    public $mobile;
    public $required;
    public $fields;
    public $showDropdown = true;


    public function mount()
    {
        foreach($this->fields as $field){
            $this->required[$field->name] = ($field->pivot->is_required == '1') ? 'required' : 'nullable';
        }
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate([
            'mobile' => [$this->required['mobile'] ?? 'nullable', new Mobile()]
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the Livewire view

```
<div>
    <div x-data="{ open: @entangle('showDropdown').defer, required: @js($required) }">
        <span x-show="open" wire:loading.remove>
            <form wire:submit.prevent="submit" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                <div class="fields">
                    @foreach($fields as $field)
                        <div class="form-{{$field->name}}">
                            @if($field->name == 'mobile')
                                <input name="{{$field->name}}" type="tel" wire:model.defer="{{ $field->name }}" placeholder="{{ __($field->pivot->placeholder ?? $field->name) }}">
                            @endif
                                @error($field->name) <span class="error">{{ ucfirst($message) }}</span> @enderror
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </form>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is here `placeholder="{{ __($field->pivot->placeholder ?? $field->name) }}"`

When the form is first loaded `$field->pivot->placeholder` is set, but after I submit the form and the validation fails, it's not set anymore and `$field->name` is used instead of `$field->pivot->placeholder`

Have checked this way:

```
<input name="{{$field->name}}" type="tel" wire:model.defer="{{ $field->name }}" placeholder="{{ __($field->pivot->placeholder ?? $field->name) }}">
{{ var_dump(isset($field->pivot->placeholder)) }}
```

When the form is first loaded it prints `bool(true)` under the field, after I send the form it says `bool(false)`

How can I get over this? Why the pivot does not work after validation fails?

//Edit: Did a workaround, but I would still like to know why it happens

What I did is I used another property `$placeholders`

In the Livewire controller have added `public $placeholders;`, in the mount() have added `$this->placeholders[$field->name] = $field->pivot->placeholder ?? $field->name;`, and then used it in the view like `placeholder="{{ __($placeholders[$field->name] ?? $field->name) }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about livewire , but I know that `mount()` only called on the initial page load meaning it will only run when you refresh the whole page or visit the page. Instead of only using `mount()` you should also use `hydrate()` which will run every subsequent request after the page load.

`mount()` - Initial Page Load

`hydrate()` - Every subsequent request

You can implement the `hydrate()` like how you implement the `mount()`